# How to navigate to "key" and grab "values"

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a data structure like the below. It is of type string. Is there a way in Python to read this and start reading as of "values" to get the values? I want to get e.g. the data.

```
                               var gIg35809469970000987890data = {
                                                                        "values": [
                                                                        [
                                                                        "34461"
                                                                        , "34461"
                                                                        , "09-03-2023"
                                                                        , "john@foe.com"
                                                                        , "indoor 1"
                                                                        , ""
                                                                        , "1"
                                                                        , "10"
                                                                        , "16"
                                                                        , ""
                                                                        , "DELETE"
                                                                        , "34461"
cut the rest for brevity
```

I tried to convert with JSON dump(s) and load(s) but it didn't work. Any ideas?

I used JSON dump(s) and load(s) to try to make a JSON object out of it, so I can navigate easily through the data. Panda could help maybe?

Comment: How is Python or JSON involved? You seem to have _JavaScript_.

Comment: Also, "it didn't work" is not a problem description: show what you tried and talk about what that did. Because "it didn't work" is never true, it worked exactly they way you told it to, and we have no idea what you told it to do until [you show your work](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks all for the replies. First question answer: I am scraping html from an Oracle APEX application which indeed uses JavaScript to generate the html pages. The data I want is enclosed in <script type=tex/javascript> tags and I cut the text between the tags. The result is the data structure show. I want to process data from this text, which looks like JSON/Dictionary. Hence if I could directly access the data from this text it would be great, as I don't have to cut the first part (e.g. remove the "var gIg35809469970000987890data = {" for example. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Yes @mike, sorry for the brevity. Long day. What I want is to access directly elements in this data structure. For example I need the "date" and "e-mail adress". Is there a simple way to access those fields? I tried to convert the object to other formats, like json.dump(s) but I get error messages, the python execution of the scripts breaks.

Comment: `json` won't help you because _it's not JSON_, even if you trim the variable declaration and assignment there's no guarantee the result will be JSON as JavaScript is more permissive (e.g. keys don't need quoting, several quote styles are allowed, things like Dates may not be serialised to parseable values, ...) Either scrape the rendered result or you'll have to parse this _as JavaScript_ in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse the text with `re` module and then use `json` to parse it. For example:

```py
import re
import json

js_text = '''\
   var gIg35809469970000987890data = {
                                        "values": [
                                        [
                                        "34461"
                                        , "34461"
                                        , "09-03-2023"
                                        , "john@foe.com"
                                        , "indoor 1"
                                        , ""
                                        , "1"
                                        , "10"
                                        , "16"
                                        , ""
                                        , "DELETE"
                                        , "34461"]]
                                };'''


data = re.search(r'var \S+data = (\{.*?\});', js_text, flags=re.S)
data = json.loads(data.group(1))

print(data['values'][0][2], data['values'][0][3])
```

Prints:

```
09-03-2023 john@foe.com
```